# How to create a Yii2 Query to get an array like given below

Tags: php, yii2

I want to get the id and name arrays as output from a query. How to do that

i need the output like this

```
[
 ['id'=>'<sub-cat-id-1>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name1>'],
 ['id'=>'<sub-cat_id_2>', 'name'=>'<sub-cat-name2>']
]
```

How to get an array like above from a yii2 query

Comment: You want to get with activerecord ? or simple query ?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you have a model as MyModel with id and name  you could use

```
$myArray =   MyModel::find()->select(['id','name'])->asArray()->all();
```